# Change folder name if it contains file type

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I am wanting to search a set of folders in a given filepath for a specific file type like so and rename the parent folder

if exist %filepath%**.bz2 rename parent folder

The problem is, I don't know what the parent folder is called every time I run the script and is subject to change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will list all folders within a directory tree that contain at least one `*.bz2` file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "root=d:\test"
for /r "%root%" %%A in (.) do if exist "%%A\*.bz2" echo %%~fA
```

You didn't state how you want to rename the folders, so you will have to figure out how to modify the above to do the rename.